# Need help sorting array and displaying it on the HTML page

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, integer

My HW assignment requires me to have a user enter integers and for it to come out on the HTML in sorted array without the sort method. I have this code and it asks the users input but the integers do not come up on page.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var arr = [];

  function addNum() {
    var n = prompt("How many integrs?", "0");
  var num = parseInt(n); 
  for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    arr[i] = parseInt(prompt("Enter next integer: ","0"));
    }

    var outputSorted = document.getElementById('outputSorted');
    outputSorted = "";
    outputSorted.append("Input array :  ");
  
    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    outputSorted.append(arr[i]+" ");
    }
  
    bubbleSort(arr);
  outputSorted.append("Sorted array :  ");
    
    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    outputSorted.append(arr[i]+" ");
    }
  }

  function bubbleSort(a) {
    var swapped;
    
    do {
      swapped = false;
      for (var i=0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
     if (a[i] > a[i+1]) {
       var temp = a[i];
       a[i] = a[i+1];
       a[i+1] = temp;
       swapped = true;
        }
      }
    } while (swapped);
  }

  function searchNum() {
    var m = parseInt(prompt("Enter num to be searched: ","0"));
 var found = binarySearch(arr, m);
 var outputSearch = document.getElementById('outputSearch');
 
    if (found == -1) {
   outputSearch.append("Number not found");
 } else {
   outputSearch.append("Number found at index : " + (found + 1));
    }
  }

  function binarySearch(array, targetValue) {
    var min = 0;
    var max = array.length - 1;
    var guess;

    while (min <= max) {
      guess = Math.floor((max + min) / 2);

      if (array[guess] === targetValue) {
        return guess;
      }
      else if (array[guess] < targetValue) {
        min = guess + 1;
      }
      else {
        max = guess - 1;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You can use `console.log()` and the developer tools from your browser for debugging :). https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_output.asp

Comment: Also maybe here `outputSorted = "";` you meant `outputSorted.innerHTML = "";`

Answer (score 0):

outputSorted is a DOM element, and append() is not a function of that element. Rather than that, use innerHTML += for each bit you want to add. See below. And note, those are the ONLY changes I made. So your ugly rendered HTML is what it is.

```js
  var arr = [];

  addNum = function addNum() {
    var n = prompt("How many integrs?", "0");
    var num = parseInt(n);
    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      arr[i] = parseInt(prompt("Enter next integer: ", "0"));
    }

    var outputSorted = document.getElementById('outputSorted');
    outputSorted.innerHTML += "Input array :  "

    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      outputSorted.innerHTML += arr[i] + " ";
    }

    bubbleSort(arr);
    outputSorted.innerHTML += "Sorted array :  ";

    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      outputSorted.innerHTML += arr[i] + " ";
    }
  }

  function bubbleSort(a) {
    var swapped;

    do {
      swapped = false;
      for (var i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
        if (a[i] > a[i + 1]) {
          var temp = a[i];
          a[i] = a[i + 1];
          a[i + 1] = temp;
          swapped = true;
        }
      }
    } while (swapped);
  }

  function searchNum() {
    var m = parseInt(prompt("Enter num to be searched: ", "0"));
    var found = binarySearch(arr, m);
    var outputSearch = document.getElementById('outputSearch');

    if (found == -1) {
      outputSearch.innerHTML += ("Number not found");
    } else {
      outputSearch.innerHTML += ("Number found at index : " + (found + 1));
    }
  }

  function binarySearch(array, targetValue) {
    var min = 0;
    var max = array.length - 1;
    var guess;

    while (min <= max) {
      guess = Math.floor((max + min) / 2);

      if (array[guess] === targetValue) {
        return guess;
      } else if (array[guess] < targetValue) {
        min = guess + 1;
      } else {
        max = guess - 1;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="addNum()">
Add some!
</button>
<div id="outputSorted">

</div>
<div id="outputSearch">

</div>
```